# Building a C library for iOS usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode

I just achieved (in testing phase) an open source C CometD library in C. After some time I thought that it would be a good idea to give the option to the user to benefit from it under Xcode for `iOS` development.

Two years ago I developed a little application in `Objective-C` and as far as I remember, I could put C code and compile it.

So I took my code and compile it as a .dylib.

**The Problem is** when i try to use it under an `Objective-C` Xcode project, at function calling i always get a  : 
- "implicit declaration error is invalid in C99" error
as well as a 
- "Source file is not valid UTF-8" error

I searched the internet to find out why but no relevant answers were found.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `implicit declaration error is invalid in C99` usually means that the function you are trying to call isn't defined. Did you include the correct header file? It would be helpful if you included your objective c code.

Comment: I don't have any Objective-C code, i just finished the C library and was hoping that it can work immediately under a Xcode generated Objective-c project, which it doesn't. I have, i guess, included properly the .so in the "Build Phases"->Link Binary With Libraries and added my .so there. Do i have to do something else ? I don't know. i found only very few documentation about this subject on the internet, which doesn't covert my issue or does't help me at all.

Comment: Is it possible c library needs other libraries linked in?

Comment: Yes as the Jansson library as well as the Curl library. Does it put sand into gears ?

Comment: Those libraries will need to be linked in at some point. I don't know if you can do it in Xcode, or if it should be done before hand when you compile your library.

Comment: I found a way, i just downloaded the source code of the two libraries, and include it the hard way on the program and it worked well :).